# How do I broadcast an EventCallback to multiple listeners in Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, blazor

Conceptually, I am having difficulty finding out how to broadcast an event to multiple components. It seems that the EventCallback property can only be set to one method. Basically, I have a service that runs a method based on window events, and I want multiple different components to be able to "subscribe" to this change.

Even a pointer towards documentation on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from using standard C# events or a list of `EventCallback` and firing the event for all the listeners in the list.  You won't be able to add listeners to the event using declaration syntax, but that doesn't seem like it'd apply for you anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing for forest for the trees trying to find a "Blazor" specific solution

Comment: @KirkWoll Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I see you found a workable alternative, but I can answer your question directly.

Blazor's `EventCallback` and `EventCallback<T>` are wrappers around traditional delegates, and traditional delegates already support exactly what you want to do.  Simply add to their invocation list, exactly as if they were an event.

Declare your delegate and add your handlers:

```
Func<string, Task>? MyDelegate { get; set;} = null;

void InitializeMyDelegate()
{
    MyDelegate += FirstHandler;
    MyDelegate += SecondHandler;
}
```

If you need to, you can have multiple classes/components subscribe to the delegate as above.

Then pass it to a component as an EventCallback normally:

```
<SomeComponent MyEvent="MyDelegate">
    // other stuff 
</SomeComponent>
```

Whenever that instance of `SomeComponent` calls `MyEvent.InvokeAsync()`, every handler you added to `MyDelegate` will be invoked.